# Curvature of spatial 2-section in general form for metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature

In this paper ([Four-Dimensional Asymptotically AdS Black Holes with Scalar Hair by Gonzalez et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2161)), the following standard metric is taken as an ansatz for the hairy black hole:

$$ds^2=-f(r)dt^2+f^{-1}(r)dr^2+a^2(r)d\sigma^2$$

where $d\sigma^2$ is the metric of the spatial 2-section, which contains the curvature. Three differential equations are derived, with one containing explicit dependence on $k$, the curvature of the spatial 2-section. However, where does the $k$-dependence come from? It's not contained in the $dr^2$ dependent term in their paper (as I've seen it written in other papers). Therefore, how would one include $k$-dependence into the $d\sigma^2$ term? I've looked for other references on the spatial 2-section, but I can only find the same authors' papers, without much discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $k$ factor does indeed come from the curvature of the 2-section metric $\mathrm{d}\sigma^2$. You can write this metric universally in "polar coordinates" as
$$\mathrm{d}\sigma^2 = \frac{\mathrm{d}\rho^2}{1-k\rho^2} + \rho^2 \mathrm{d}\varphi^2$$
$k=1$ corresponds to the unit 2-sphere (you will probably recognize the parametrization $\rho=\sin\vartheta$ better), $k=0$ to the flat plane ($\rho$ is then just the polar radius), and $k=-1$ to the hyperbolic plane. There are other ways to write these metrics, but the factor in the Einstein equations would always turn out the same. This can be easily verified by computing the curvature of the 2-section metric and by computing the Einstein equations directly.

Comment: So I assume when I solve Einstein's equations I would take derivatives with respect to t, r, $\rho$, and $\phi$, correct? (as opposed to taking them with respect to $t$, $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$ as we usually do for a simple metric specifically for $k=1$). Also, isn't the regular parametrization for $\rho=\sin\theta$?

Comment: You can choose any set of coordinates and then compute the Einstein equations in them. The only point to remember is that you need to be consistent, i.e., take derivatives wrt coordinates in which your coordinate components are expressed. (And yes, $\rho = \sin \vartheta$ with $\vartheta \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is the more usual choice, I will make an edit to reflect that.)